# Redirect From a Js File

Tags: php, javascript, html

I am using this code in php or html file for redirect

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js"></script>

<script language="JavaScript">


var country= geoip_country_code();

if(country == "US" )
{
<!--
window.location = "http://google.com"

//-->
}

</script>
```

but i want to use a js file  which do the same function but its extension should be .js

as http://domain.com/redirect.js so what would be the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This includes a script include function with a callback, so that the Maxmind client code won't run until the Maxmind library has been loaded.

```
loadScript("http://j.maxmind.com/app/geoip.js", function() {
    var country = geoip_country_code();

    if (country === "US") {
        window.location = "http://google.com/";
    }
});

function loadScript(url, callback) {
    // adding the script tag to the head as suggested before
   var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
   var script = document.createElement('script');
   script.type = 'text/javascript';
   script.src = url;

   // then bind the event to the callback function 
   // there are several events for cross browser compatibility
   script.onreadystatechange = callback;
   script.onload = callback;

   // fire the loading
   head.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: The best way to let me know is to upvote and choose mine as the correct answer. :)